# How to use Twilio AndroidSDK behind sock proxy

Tags: android, twilio

I will use Twilio AndroidSDK.
i need using Twilio AndroidSDK behind socks5 proxy.

I wrote this code under ClientActivity.java in twilio-mobile-quickstart
https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client

```
public static class MyProxySelector extends ProxySelector {
    private ProxySelector delegate;

    public MyProxySelector(ProxySelector delegate){
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Proxy> select(URI uri){
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress("[MY-SOCKS5-SERVER-IP HERE]",1080));
        List<Proxy> select = new ArrayList<Proxy>();
        select.add(proxy);
        System.out.println("Use Socks5 Proxy Server: " + select);
        return select;
    }

    @Override
    public void connectFailed(URI uri, SocketAddress sa, IOException ioe){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not Supported yet");
    }


}
```

and add initialize code ProxySelector between "// proxyselector" and "//eol"

```
/*
 * Initialize the Twilio Client SDK
 */
private void initializeTwilioClientSDK() {

    if (!Twilio.isInitialized()) {
        // proxyselector
        ProxySelector proxySelector = ProxySelector.getDefault();

        ProxySelector myProxySelector = new MyProxySelector(proxySelector);
        ProxySelector.setDefault(myProxySelector);
        // eof

        Twilio.initialize(getApplicationContext(), new Twilio.InitListener() {
```

Anyone might have an idea where did i do wrong? Thanks in advance.

---- Add info: Android Monitor log

```
01-31 10:34:40.906 20853-20939/com.twilio.client.quickstart D/libGLESv1: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.twilio.client.quickstart
01-31 10:34:40.926 20853-20954/com.twilio.client.quickstart I/System.out: Use Default Proxy List[SOCKS@/59.106.213.62:1080]
<snip>
01-31 10:34:41.606 20853-20853/com.twilio.client.quickstart I/PJSIP: 10:34:41.618    pjsua_acc.c  ..Contact for acc 1 updated for SIP outbound: <sip:phtest@MY-CLIENT-ANDROID-IP:38888;transport=TLS;ob>;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000e922f243>"
```

Comment: What errors are you receiving?

Comment: Hi. I'm not receive error in android monitor. MyProxySelector class can't running...

Comment: i received log "01-31 10:34:40.906 20853-20939/com.twilio.client.quickstart D/libGLESv1: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.twilio.client.quickstart
01-31 10:34:40.926 20853-20954/com.twilio.client.quickstart I/System.out: Use Default Proxy List[SOCKS@/MY-SOCKS5-SERVER-IP:1080]" class is can runnig. I seeing socks5 server log can't running. Twilio SDK was directlly connect to twilio servers.

Comment: i got simplly idea. use in system properties. [NewQuestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41951879/how-to-use-twilio-androidsdk-behind-sock-proxy-with-java-system-property) but i no fixed this issue