# How to use Twilio AndroidSDK behind sock proxy with Java System Property

Tags: android, twilio

I will use Twilio AndroidSDK. i need using Twilio AndroidSDK behind socks5 proxy.

I wrote [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client) code under ClientActivity.java in twilio-mobile-quickstart

NEW IDEA: no use ProxySelector. only Systems Property Connecting..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies","true");
    System.setProperty("proxyHost","[Proxy Server Addr]");
    System.setProperty("proxyPort","[Proxy Server Port]");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost","[Proxy Server Addr]");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort","[Proxy Server Port]");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost","[Proxy Server Addr]");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort","[Proxy Server Port]");
    System.setProperty("socketsProxyHost","[SOCKS5 Server Addr]");
    System.setProperty("socketsProxyPort","[SOCKS5 Server Port]");
```

I get new errors. can't connecting SSL.
i feel my device connect to host directlly.

Twilio this https connection can't connect with proxies? :(

in closed network, detect this log:

```
01-31 16:17:15.617 17711-30305/com.twilio.client.quickstart D/HttpLongPollThread: connecting to host matrix.twilio.com on port 443
01-31 16:17:15.697 17711-30305/com.twilio.client.quickstart W/HttpLongPollThread: long poller got exception
                                                                              java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to matrix.twilio.com/52.54.166.186 (port 443) after 30000ms: isConnected failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
                                                                                  at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:234)
                                                                                  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:171)
                                                                                  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
                                                                                  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
                                                                                  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:452)
                                                                                  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884)
                                                                                  at com.twilio.client.impl.net.HttpLongPollThread.setUpSocket(HttpLongPollThread.java:62)
                                                                                  at com.twilio.client.impl.net.HttpLongPollThread.run(HttpLongPollThread.java:287)
                                                                               Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
                                                                                  at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:223)
                                                                                  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:171) 
                                                                                  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122) 
                                                                                  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183) 
                                                                                  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:452) 
                                                                                  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884) 
                                                                                  at com.twilio.client.impl.net.HttpLongPollThread.setUpSocket(HttpLongPollThread.java:62) 
                                                                                  at com.twilio.client.impl.net.HttpLongPollThread.run(HttpLongPollThread.java:287)
```

Anyone might have an idea where did i do wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid the Twilio Client Android SDK does not currently support SOCKS proxies, which is why you are seeing these issues.

I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) with your requirements and they will be able to notify you if proxy support is added to the SDK.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: @SSaka please do contact Twilio support, it's the best way to show the need for this kind of feature. Thanks!